# Not able to add values entered in inputfield to the existing value from previous page

Tags: jquery, datatables, salesforce, visualforce

I have the following code in place which correctly sums the values that i enter in the Inputfield of the data table and displays the total on the footer. When I click on Next the summed value of the first page is taken to the Second page, but when I try entering the value, it sums from starting, that is, it doesn't sum to the carry forwarded value from the first page.

Eg: In the first page i enter:
120
300
the footer shows=420
I click on 'next', the footer carry forwards the value 420
Now when i enter 300, the footer sum displays as 300, but i would want it to be 420+300=720.
I have been trying several ways but found no luck. Any help is very much appreciated.

// this is the code. I am calling this method in input tag using onkeyup=updateTotal;

```
function updateTotal() {
var Total_Sum=0.00; 
$("#invtbl").children("tbody").children().each(function(){
var valueAmount=$(this).children("td:nth-child(7)").children("input").val();
if(!isNaN(parseInt(valueAmount)))        {Total_Sum=Total_Sum+parseFloat(valueAmount);}
    else if( valueAmount.charAt( 0 ) === '-' && !isNaN(parseInt(valueAmount.slice(1)))) {Total_Sum=Total_Sum-parseFloat(valueAmount.slice(1));}
    else if( valueAmount.charAt( 0 ) === '+' && !isNaN(parseInt(valueAmount.slice(1)))) {Total_Sum=Total_Sum+parseFloat(valueAmount.slice(1));}
  });
  totalAmountToBeDisplayedonPDF=Total_Sum;
  var decimalVal=currencyFormat(Total_Sum);
  $("#invtbl").children("tfoot").children().children("th:nth-child(4)").text(decimalVal);
}
```

Comment: Are these two different Visualforce pages?  Do you have anything to pass the value from the first page to the second page?  Can you post more of your code?